# Parse certain values from Google Maps XML to Excel cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a link `"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=..."` that I access to get XML file data.

XML file:

```
<DistanceMatrixResponse>
<status>OK</status>
<origin_address>London, UK</origin_address>
<destination_address>Manchester, UK</destination_address>
<row>
<element>
<status>OK</status>
<duration>
<value>14735</value>
<text>4 hours 6 mins</text>
</duration>
<distance>
<value>335534</value>
<text>336 km</text>
</distance>
</element>
</row>
</DistanceMatrixResponse>
```

XML file structure is always the same. I need to get `<text>4 hours 6 mins</text>` and `<text>336 km</text>` in form of `4,6` to cell A1 and `336` to cell A2 lets say "Contact database". Also problem here is that `<text>4 hours 6 mins</text>` sometimes can be `<text>1 hour 3 min</text>`. I can do it with formula but is it even possible with VBA?

I have managed to make it work so that the whole XML file data is in cell A1. However not able to separate what I need and paste to two different cells.

```
Sub GoogleAPI1()
Dim xmlhttp As Object
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
Dim myurl As String

myurl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Contact database").Range("R86").Value _
& "&destinations=" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Contact database").Range("R87").Value & "&mode=" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Contact database").Range("R88").Value _
& "&key=" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Contact database").Range("R82").Value

xmlhttp.Open "GET", myurl, False
xmlhttp.send
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Contact database").Range("R92") = xmlhttp.responseText
End Sub
```

Comment: You can do this easily with formulas or VBA.  Any special reason to prefer VBA?

Comment: This one works now with formulas. I use for example FILTERXML to get values out of <text></text> tags. I was just thinking it is better to do all by one VBA code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to use VBA to get the results you describe.

I extracted the node information, and then processed it using Regular Expressions to get it into the format you described.

Could probably do it more efficiently, and with more or different error-checking, but this might get you started.

```
Option Explicit
Sub getDurDist()
    Dim xmlDoc As DOMDocument60
    Dim xmlNode As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Dim rDest As Range

Set xmlDoc = New DOMDocument60

'hard coded here.  Change to suit
Set rDest = Range("B1:C1")
rDest.Clear

xmlDoc.LoadXML Range("a1")
Set xmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//duration/text")


sTemp = xmlNode.Text

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "\d+"
    If .test(sTemp) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(sTemp)
        rDest(1, 1) = MC(0) & "," & MC(1)
    End If
End With


Set xmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//distance/text")
sTemp = xmlNode.Text
With RE
    If .test(sTemp) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(sTemp)
        rDest(1, 2) = MC(0)
    End If
End With

End Sub
```